# Re-Use of CBV in a different app

Tags: django, django-views, mixins

I need some help in understanding how to implement a photo upload in 2 different app and keeping my project DRY. I have an app (gallery) where I defined 3 different view (it's practically an implementation of django-jquery-file-upload example in git: https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload)

```
class PictureCreateView(CreateView)
    ...
class PictureDeleteView(DeleteView):
    ...
class PictureListView(ListView):
    ...
```

This 3 class are used in the same template to choose multiple photo to upload (and eventually delete) to the server. Everything works fine within the gallery app but now I'd like to use all there 3 views in 2 different app (and models). The gallery models is the following:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField()
    place = models.ForeignKey(
        'app_place.Poi',
        related_name='places',
        null=True, blank=True,
    )
    event = models.ForeignKey(
        'app_event.Event',
        related_name='events',
        null=True, blank=True,
    )
```

So that each photo could be related to an event (or place). I'd like to use the 3 views from the gallery app in the event and place DetailView (all authenticated users can add photo to places or events) which belongs to 2 different apps... what is the correct approach? Trying to define the 3 gallery views as mixin? Or call them using the get_context_data? I don't know how to proceed and nay help/suggestion is wellcome

Comment: Your example calls for generic foreign keys:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Comment: I had a look and this is ok to simplify the Picture model (one single generic foreign key instead of the two I have now) but doesn't sole my major problem... how can I use the 3 view from the gallery app in the 2 different DetailView (one in the Event app and the other one in the Place all)?